# append function not working in for loop Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, append

I have a for loop running that creates a new list of select Unix times from elements of another list containing multiple Unix times, the index of those elements is in turn given by another list. My problem is that within this for loop the append function is not working and I have no idea why as I get no errors. The print function is simply ignored after the for loop. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Could someone help me out?

Here is my code:

```
adjusted_exc_pass_numbers = [0, 6, 9, 16, 19, 22, 25, 32, 35, 41, 48]
processed_start_times = [1519275660, 1519287600, 1519325040, 1519336920, 1519360080, 1519365900, 1519371900, 1519409400, 1519415340, 1519421280, 1519450260, 1519456200, 1519499700, 1519534680, 1519540560, 1519546620, 1519584060, 1519596000, 1519619160, 1519624920, 1519630920, 1519668420, 1519674360, 1519680360, 1519709340, 1519715220, 1519758720, 1519793760, 1519799580, 1519805700, 1519843080, 1519855020, 1519878180, 1519884000, 1519890000, 1519927500, 1519939380, 1519968360, 1519974300, 1520017800, 1520052780, 1520058660, 1520064720, 1520102160]
ppst = []
for element in range(len(adjusted_exc_pass_numbers)):
    ppst.append(processed_start_times[int(adjusted_exc_pass_numbers[element])])
print(ppst)
```

When I run this, print is ignored and the rest of the code executes as if the statement was not there. I don't understand why it is not appending or printing.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This script fails with an error. If you can't see the error you should run it differently (e.g. from commandline)

Comment: Why not just `ppst = [adjusted_exc_pass_numbers[index] for index in processed_start_times]`? Iterating over `range(len(thing))` is generally unidiomatic in Python.

Comment: You get an error because the last element of `adjusted_exc_pass_numbers` is 48 and `processed_start_times` only has 44 elements. Hence in the loop Python can't get the 48th element of `processed_start_times` and IndexErrors.

Comment: Also you shouldn't use a loop, as `jonrsharpe` mentioned. also try: `list(map(processed_start_times.__getitem__, adjusted_exc_pass_numbers))`

Comment: Avoid `for element in range(len(x)):`, just use `for element in x:`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried your method but it doesn't work for me. Again no error is reported in IDLE. I will change the range thing though.

Comment: It should absolutely report an error: as everyone else has pointed out, you're trying to access an index beyond the end of the list. My suggestion didn't change that problem, it's just a neater way to express the same logic.

Comment: Which Python version on which OS do you use?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I understand. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I am using 3.6.4 on Windows 10.

Comment: Also, I'm sorry but I have changed the length of the 44 element list so that it is the full 52 elements long and I am still having the same issue.

Comment: If you use IDLE to run the code, try to run some simple test code like `bla`. If you don't get a traceback with `NameError` as response it makes no sense to fix a particular error in your code because you won't be able to see any further errors (which will occur).

Comment: @MichaelButscher I understand and I'll give it a go. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run this code I get an IndexError at the line

```
ppst.append(processed_start_times[int(adjusted_exc_pass_numbers[element])])
```

The reason for this is because as you are iterating, element will be 0,1,2,3..., `adjusted_exc_pass_numbers[element]` will be 0,6,9,16,..., and eventually you will be trying to get index 48 from `processed_start_times`, a list which only has 44 entries. Not sure why you are completing the loop without any errors but this is the problem as far as I can tell.